# Route not defined react router and spring boot server

Tags: reactjs, spring, react-router

I want to add react-route to my app, i have the code below:

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

```
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './App.js';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}> 
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> 
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                Hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I have a spring boot server which listens on 8080, in browser i get error when checking localhost:8080 (debug mozilla):

```
ReferenceError: Route is not defined
```

I have  "react-router": "^4.1.1".

EDIT:
imported route but i get now:

```
TypeError: i.props.history is undefined
```

UPDATE:
Installed react-router 3.0.2 and worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just import Route from react-router

`import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router';`

Comment: After importing route i get: TypeError: i.props.history is undefined

Answer (score 1):

Let's get right at the solution, here. The error is misleading. You're missing something from this index.js:

```
import {StrictMode} from 'react'
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './styles/globals.css'
import { store } from './store/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const rootElement = document.querySelector('#main')
const root = createRoot(rootElement)

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BrowserRouter or HashRouter from react-router-dom package, not Router from react-router package, if you are using react router in a webbrowser.

You should never need to import react-router yourself, react-router-dom will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

for those who are struggling with
Attempted **import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.**

1). Uninstall Previous Version By => npm uninstall react-router-dom
2). Install the Older version By => npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0

Because After v6 Switch is Not included in react-router-dom

Another Solution is:-
For the New Version of react-router-dom

Instead of using like this

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/users">
      <Users />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

**Use like this...**

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
  </Routes>
```